# Excel VBA: Lock a buttons aspect ratio via code

Tags: vba, excel, button

I have the following code to place Buttons on a sheet on specific cells.

```
Sub insertRowButtons()
    Dim btn As Button
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Dim t As Range

    'to show details for all groups
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels rowlevels:=5

    'use this lines for rows
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array(20, 32, 44, 56)

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
       Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(arr(i), 4), Cells(arr(i), 4))
       Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
       With btn
         .OnAction = "insertItemRows"
         .Caption = "Btn " & i
         .Name = "Btn" & i
       End With
    Next i

    'set group detail back to standard view
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels rowlevels:=4
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

When I run the code everything works fine except that the placed Buttons have not set the 'Lock Aspect Ratio'-Option set to true. As you can, see in the following picture, it is quite needed to lock the aspect ratio. When I insert the Buttons some rows below are hidden.

When the rows are hidden and I place the buttons and unhide the rows afterwards, then the button resizes itself.

(Button with red cross is aspect ratio locked manually, blue cross is without the lock)

[image]

Please tell me how to set the "Lock Aspect Ratio" to true in the code without doing it manually via the buttons "Format Control".

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can only LockAspectRatio on a shape object, so try this in your loop:

```
       With btn
         .OnAction = "insertItemRows"
         .Caption = "Btn " & i
         .Name = "Btn" & i             
          ActiveSheet.Shapes(.Name).LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
       End With
```

Comment: First of all, thank you because it works. It sets the buttons Lock Aspect Ratio = true. (I just checked it in the buttons 'Control Format'. The weird thing is: When the rows below a button are hidden when I run the code and I unhide them afterwards, then the button still resizes like it does before (see the picture I posted) even though the button got the lock aspect ration on true.

Comment: Just to give you an update. I made a little "workaround". Now I use `ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels rowlevels:=5´  in the beginning to show all my grouped rows. In the end I set it back to 4 (the standard view).